# Group dates based on variable periods

Tags: mysql, sql

i have two tables  as follows------

**table-1**

```
CalenderType  periodNumber periodstartdate
1             1            01-01-2013
1             2            11-01-2013
1             3            15-01-2013
1             4            25-01-2013
2             1            01-01-2013
2             2            15-01-2013
2             3            20-01-2013
2             4            25-01-2013
```

**table2**

```
Incidents  Date
xyz        02-01-2013
xxyyzz     03-01-2013
ccvvb      12-01-2013
vvfg       16-01-2013
x3         17-01-2013
x5         24-01-2013
```

Now i want to find out the number of incidents took place in a given period(the Calendar type may change on runtime like)
the query should look something like this

```
select ....... 
from ......
where CalendarType=1
```

which should return

```
CalendarType PeriodNumber Incidents
1            1            2
1            2            1
1            3            3
1            4            0
```

can someone suggest me an approach or any method how this can be achieved.

Note:each `period` is variable in `size.peroid1` may have 10 days `period2` may have 5 days etc.

Comment: Do periods ever overlap or have the same start date?

Comment: Why is the incident count 1 for period 4? There are no incidents after 2013-01-24 and period 4 starts on 2013-01-25.

Comment: @RedFilter, no the periods dont overlap . Yes period4 should be 0
and period3 should be 3(my mistake).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this does what you want, although I don't understand how you arrived at your sample output:

```
select t.CalenderType, t.periodNumber, count(*) as Incidents
from Table1 t
inner join (
  select t2.Date, t2.Incidents, max(t1.periodstartdate) as PeriodStartDate
  from Table2 t2
  inner join Table1 t1 on t2.Date >= t1.periodstartdate
  where CalenderType = 1
  group by t2.Date, t2.Incidents
) a on t.periodstartdate = a.PeriodStartDate
where CalenderType=1
group by t.CalenderType, t.periodNumber
```

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a25af/67)

Comment: I think your sub-select's inner join needs to be changed to the following: `inner join Table1 t1 on t2.Date >= t1.periodstartdate`.  Otherwise if the incident's date falls on the period's start date, it will not be counted for that date range.

Comment: @Tom agreed, changed query accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Try this, a bit more general solution,[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a25af/73/0) (Thanks RedFilter for schema):

```
SELECT t1.CalenderType,  t1.periodNumber, count(Incidents)
FROM Table1 t1, Table1 t11, Table2 
WHERE 
(
  (
    t1.CalenderType = t11.CalenderType 
    AND t1.periodNumber = t11.periodNumber - 1
    AND Date BETWEEN t1.periodstartdate AND t11.periodstartdate 
  ) 
  OR
  (
    t1.periodNumber = (SELECT MAX(periodNumber) FROM Table1 WHERE t1.CalenderType = CalenderType)
    AND Date > t1.periodstartdate
  )

) 
GROUP BY  t1.CalenderType,  t1.periodNumber
ORDER BY  t1.CalenderType,  t1.periodNumber
```

Comment: I think you need to change your WHERE clause for the dates to this: `(Date >= t1.periodstartdate AND Date < t11.periodstartdate)`.  Otherwise if the date matches the start date of the second period, it will incorrectly be counted under the first.

Comment: @Tom I know, lets treat this answer like draft :]